# `md-center-tabs` attribute of `md-tabs` in AngularJS Material 1.1.7 not working properly on mobile

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

Is anyone else having an issue with the `md-center-tabs` attribute for `md-tabs` in AngularJS Material 1.1.7?

We recently upgraded from AngularJS Material 1.1.3, which is when I observed it to be working as intended and stated in the documentation.  We upgraded in order to take advantage of the upgraded `md-datepicker` directive in Angular JS Material 1.1.7.  Anyway, here is the documentation that I am referencing for `md-tabs`:

https://material.angularjs.org/latest/api/directive/mdTabs

On mobile screen sizes (i.e. smaller viewports) the tabs end up getting scrunched up as show below:

[image: Deal Console - Mobile View]

I have tried to use `md-stretch-tabs` to "offset/counter" this issue; however, that does not seem to solve the problem.  We **had not** used `md-stretch-tabs` when coding in AngularJS Material 1.1.3 and presumably `md-center-tabs` was automatically stretching each individual tab to be equal to the viewport size on smaller screen sizes, where users could scroll through all `md-tabs` as shown below:

[image]

I've searched the web endlessly hoping that someone might be having the same issue here or on Github, but cannot find anything.  Hopefully, it's such a small nit that someone can help me figure out an easy workaround.

Comment: Can you able to simulate your issue in [codepen](https://codepen.io) or any editor and show us.

Comment: Unfortunately, Arjun simulating the issue in codepen etc. would require burning too many brain cells because it would require supplanting a lot of custom code in order to recreate the issue.